# Using psalm in .phtml files

Tags: php, static-analysis, psalm-php

I'm trying to make psalm work on `.phtml` files.
Everything goes well, except for one thing. All classes (which should be autoloaded) are undefined. In normal php classes they get loaded by psalm.

Following gives `UndefinedDocblockClass` for `CustomBlocks`.

```
//my-template.phtml

<?php 
use MyNamespace\Block\CustomBlocks

/** @var CustomBlocks $block */
?>
```

Whilst adding `OneRandomClass` it doesn't give that error anymore.

```
//my-template.phtml

<?php 
use MyNamespace\Block\CustomBlocks

/** @var CustomBlocks $block */

class OneRandomClass {

}
?>
```

Update; the 2nd example doesn't give that error because the docblock is associated with the following class & the @var is ignored in class docblocks.

Comment: Does it work if you put a `;` at the end of the line?

Comment: Do you mean like `/** @var CustomBlocks $block */;`? No, nothing changes

Comment: https://github.com/vimeo/psalm/issues/4162